What does an isolated dash mean in figured bass?
(Note that these do not seem to be the same as the isolated lines discussed in What does an isolated horizontal dash mean in figured bass notation)
I am trying to work with a figured bass score that has frequent horizontal dashes in the figured bass line that are completely isolated from any figures. 
How should these be interpreted? Is there a more common way of showing the same thing?

My first thought was that it's a worksheet intending you to fill in the answer. Can you tell more about this score or name the piece? Can you provide the upper voices, so we can see what chord it really is? Voting to close as "lacking details or clarity" until edited.

Agreed, don't make us guess, show the full staff, and explain more about the source/purpose of the score. What is the publication date? If you play the dashes literally as holding the harmony it sounds like a modern style with lots of "sus", "add", or "slash" chords.

I've updated the example to include the upper voices. Definitely not modern style - Carlos Seixas - but it's been through some uncertain transcriptions before it's got to me.

Well it's certainly not about "sustaining the previous chord." The chords with A in the bass are simple A minor. In other words, removing the dashes would have no effect on the reading. Which leads me to think they have nothing to do with figured bass at all? They don't make much sense as wayward tenuto marks either. I'm inclined to ignore them.

As with a dash following a figure, it means that the preceding harmony does not change.  Since the preceding harmony is unfigured, it is implicitly 5 over 3, a root-position triad, in this case E minor.  That means that this should be, in lead sheet notation, Em/A, which is a bit weird.
It is weird enough that I would suspect it of being an error.  Normally you'd expect to see 6 (or 6 over 5) there; another possibility is of course to have it unfigured as a iv chord.
It's possible that the editor assumed that the dash meant that the e.g. the A should bear the same figure as the preceding note -- in this case none, which makes more sense harmonically but does not reflect how dashes were actually used in the period.  It's also possible that the A should be a G, in which case the dash indicates the same harmony as a 6 would, and the 6 is in my experience the more common way to figure that.
From the second measure, I would infer that the editor might think that the dash indicates 5 over 3, but then again there's no such mark on the first note of the example.
What is the piece?  What is the edition?  What sources are available for the piece?  What figures do they show?  The more I think about it, the more I think that the editor has misread the source somehow.

Reverse-engineering the editor's thought process, it might be "use a dash on all root-position chords in lieu of a figure, except for repeated notes." Which would also be odd. Perhaps a more Ockham-friendly possibility is that the typesetter has inexpertly rendered long dashes, perhaps long dashed lines, from the original, e.g. the second measure is meant to simply sustain the Am throughout three beats. If these were a dashed line in the original and printed in moveable type, it's easy to imagine an uninformed eye trying to assign each separate dash to a specific note.

There were similar problems with slur markings in the Capriccio Stravagante that I did my dissertation on; a passage strewn with equal-sized and equally-spaced slur marks that I believe just meant "use slurs, ad libitum," but was sometimes rendered with careful scrutiny, aligning the slurs to the nearest dot, with un-idiomatic results.

@AndyBonner it might, but then you need something else to explain the lack of a dash on the initial E. (I assume you mistyped and meant "Em" for the first three beats of the second measure.)  Misunderstanding movable type is a very likely hypothesis, though in my experience (early 17C, mostly Monteverdi) movable type is very sparsely figured -- and often full of errors of its own.)

It's from the "Et Resurrexit" from Seixas' Mass in G. It's gone through quite a few transcriptions from a proper published edition, so errors are quite possible. I suppose I'll have to try a bit more ear training then listening to a performance!

@digitig thanks.  Who published the proper published edition?  Is the manuscript available anywhere?

I've been trying to find a manuscript, but all I've found so far is someone else who was looking for a copy a year ago, and the score for a single movement with a realisation of the bass instead of the figuring. I'll have to try reverse-engineering that realisation to figure out the thinking of the transcriber of the copy I have.

@digitig The original is apparently in a cathedral archive in Portugal: https://rism.online/sources/110002480 I don't see a digital copy online, but the archivists might be willing to help out.  Unfortunately, the RISM entry seems to have misidentified the location of the archive; I don't see a cathedral archive in Viseu, and the municipal archive does not see, to list this piece, so it seems as though it will take some detective work to get to the bottom of it.

@digtig sorry, it's the district archive, not municipal, that has some liturgical holdings: https://advis.dglab.gov.pt/fundos-e-colecoes/musica-e-liturgia/ where I do not see this mass.  But to be honest, you can just derive the figures from analysis of the full score; full scores typically didn't include figures because the purpose of the figures is primarily to communicate information about the harmony, and that information is already present in the full score.  Any discrepancy between that and the b.c. part would most likely be an error in the part.

That gave me the idea of looking in the British Library collection, to see if they had it as a figured bass or a realisation, but no. As I say, I'll try matching the one movement I can find a score for (with a realisation) with the figured bass version I have. If I can figure out (no pun intended) how it had been figured there I might be able to work out the pattern.

@digitig if you don't have a score for the other movements, do you have any other parts?  I'm half seriously thinking of a trip to Portugal.  But more seriously, the district archive seems to offer digital images on request.  It's not clear to me whether they have this manuscript, but if mot they should certainly be able to give the contact information of the arch that does, and if so they may scan it for you.

@phoog A holiday in Portugal is about due - I've only been there for work. Though how my family will take to me spending the holiday exploring the Viseu cathedral archives I'm not sure. :)
